# What is the best linear regression method when the errors in the variables x and y are unknown?

Tags: regression, errors-in-variables

I have pairs of observations $(X_i,Y_i)$ with errors in both variables and I need to find the line that best fits the data. I have found some methods, but it is essential to know the standard deviation of the errors of $X_i$ and $Y_i$ or the ratio of error variances. What method could I use if I don't know these values? What is the best?

I found a report by Gillard & Iles (2005) that explains the Method of Moments Estimation. This method allows the regression to be performed under different circumstances including the case when nothing is known about errors. Is there any other method for this case?

I also would like to know if there is any software to perform linear regression using the Method of Moments Estimation?

Gillard & Iles, 2005. Method of Moments Estimation in Linear Regression with Errors in both Variables

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Standard deviations of what?

Comment: I think what you're describing is a linear _functional_ relationship which (without any additional assumptions) will be difficult to estimate. Have a look at [this classic paper by Solari](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2517-6161.1969.tb00797.x) for why this is problem, as well as [this textbook by Nagelkerke](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-2858-5).